# Precalculus-level Projective Geometry Reference

Tags: reference-request, education, projective-geometry

I'm teaching a course right now at the pre-calculus level (an "ideas in math" class) and would like to know if anyone knows of

1) A nice source of problems
and/or
2) An accessible set of notes that the students can read.

I don't need a lot of material; we're not going much beyond the definitions (adding "points at infinity" to the plane, and a short discussion of projective coordinates). I'll write my own materials if I can't find anything I really like, but I'd rather not re-invent the wheel, and a quick Google search hasn't turned up anything useful.

Comment: I chose to post here rather on the math educators' stack, with the idea that this audience might have more familiarity with the topic, but feel free to migrate the question if it's more appropriate there.

Comment: I included a chapter on affine and projective geometry at the end of my (college level) abstract algebra text. There are the various classical results in there (Desargues, Pappus, Pascal) and a discussion of projective duality.  I did frame things in terms of homogeneous coordinates and the space of lines through the origin in $\Bbb R^3$, etc. But you might find some problems to steal ... You can find more info on my webpage, linked in the profile.

Answer (score 0):

I think the text:

*Viewpoints: Mathematical Perspective and Fractal Geometry in Art*

by Marc Frantz, Annalisa Crannell

ISBN-13: 978-0691125923
ISBN-10: 0691125929

might be something you're looking for.

I have worked some of the problems and read some of the text and it seems to be a hands on introduction to some of the basic concepts in projective geometry.

Get back to me if you look at it and think it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

checked my mostly unread Dover math used book collection

Introduction to Projective Geometry, Wylie

Linear Geometry, Artzy

Projective Geometries and Projective Metrics, Busemann and Kelly

A Modern View of Geometry, Blumenthal

all have at least a chapter on Projective Geometry

Geometric Algebra is useful in Projective/Homogeneous modeling

Geometric Algebra for Computer Science, Dorst, Fontain, Mann has a chapter or two that are relevant, although the doulbly homogeneous 5-D model of 3-D Euclidean space is the main thrust

Answer (score 0):

*Projective Geometry* by Coxeter (2nd edition, Springer-verlag) could be helpful for you and your students.

This small book contains a lot of exercices and their solutions (since there are solutions, it might be more suitable for you, in order to prepare your notes and your problems, than for your students).